# class based views, response headers and CORS

Tags: django, cors, django-rest-framework

Apologies if this is a very basic question but I am relatively new to web development and have been stuck on this for most of today on the below issues - any help is greatly appreciated.

**1. Generic class based views**

I'm really just going through the tutorial here and modifying this for my own basic needs and have ended up with the basic view as follows:

```
class EList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    model = trax 
    #permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)
    serializer_class = TraxSerializer
```

What will be posting to this api is an external service which I am also building which means I am running into cross origin resource sharing issues (CORS). Ideally I would need to set the headers to something like `["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*"` but am unsure how to do this using these generic class based views even after searching for this. Is this possible and I have just been looking in the wrong place?

I had found [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-rest-framework/l-NZr7uIznw), where Tom had mentioned that it was possible, but can't seem to work this into my above view which leads me on to the next step

**2.) Class based views**

To try and get a bit more flexibility around setting the headers and to try out what I found in the post on CORS I decided to revert back to a standard class based view as below:

```
class EList(APIView):
    """
    List all snippets, or create a new snippet.
    """
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        trax = trax.objects.all()
        serializer = TraxSerializer(trax, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    def post(self, request, format=None):  
        serializer = TraxSerializer(data=request.DATA)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

However I get the following error:

> Cannot apply DjangoModelPermissions on a view that does not have
>   `.model` or `.queryset` property.

Is there any way around this so I can try out setting response headers here? This is my current permissions as well:

```
'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly',
    ]
```

Thanks for any help,

Comment: What client do you use to make the post request? Is it jquery, angularjs or some mobile app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make this work, you need to allow the external web service to make cross-origin request. The easiest way to do it is by installing [django-cors-headers](https://github.com/OttoYiu/django-cors-headers) package and add your service hostname in the `settings.py` like so:

```
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'myservice.com',
)
```

where `myservice.com` is the external service that makes the ajax call. Also remember to follow [these setup instructions](https://github.com/OttoYiu/django-cors-headers#setup).

Comment: I did end up using this very helpful package

Answer (score 0):

For Django Framework itself, you can do the following:

Instead of URL 'https://origin.com' you can place a wildcard '*' or any other URL.

```
class PriceListTableView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "pages/price_list_table.html"

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
        response['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = 'https://origin.com'
        return response
```

Might or might not apply to Django REST Framework.